# Spring cloud Feign Client cant use @ModelAttribute?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud

How can i  use `@ModelAttribute` with GET method of request

```
@FeignClient("xx")
interface UserService{

   @RequestMapping(value="/users",method=GET)
   public List<User> findBy(@ModelAttribute User user);
}

userService.findBy(user);
```

Comment: You asked us this 23 days ago https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/792. It was marked as a duplicate of https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/617. This won't work until that issue is closed (or when it is actually worked on).

Comment: yes,I want to know somebody can help to resolve it.and i found feign `@Param(expander=ToStringExpander.class)` to convert to string,so if spring cloud can custom expender like ToJsonExpander,and server custom argumentResolver to convert to model.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621062/how-to-custom-feignclient-expander-to-convert-param/35835085#35835085