# How to validate request parameters on feign client

Tags: validation, feign

Is there a way to add validation to feign clients on the request parameters.

For example:

```java
@FeignClient
public interface ZipCodeClient {
    @GetMapping("/zipcodes/{zipCode}")
    Optional<ZipCodeView> findByZipCode(@PathVariable("zipCode") String zipCode);
}
```

It would be nice to verify that zipcode is not empty and is of certain length etc, before sending the HTTP call to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If your validations are simple, apply to only headers and query string parameters, you can use a `RequestInterceptor` for this, as it provides you the opportunity to review the `RequestTemplate` before it is sent to the `Client`.

```java
public class ValidatingRequestInterceptor implements RequestInterceptor {
   public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
      // use the methods on the request template to check the query and values.
      // throw an exception if the request is not valid.
   }
}
```

If you need to validate the request body, you can use a custom `Encoder`

```java
public class ValidatingEncoder implements Encoder {
   public void encode(Object object, Type type, RequestTemplate template) {
      // validate the object
      // throw an exception if the request is not valid.
   }
}
```

Lastly, if you want to validate individual parameters, you can provide a custom `Expander` for the parameter and validate it there.  You can look at this answer for a complete explanation on how to create a custom expander that can work with Spring Cloud.

[How to custom @FeignClient Expander to convert param？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35621062/how-to-custom-feignclient-expander-to-convert-param/35835085#35835085)

For completeness, I've included an example for how to do this with vanilla Feign.

```java
public class ZipCodeExpander implements Expander {
   public String expand(Object value) {
      // validate the object
      // throw an exception if the request is not valid.
   }
}

public interface ZipCodeClient {
    @RequestLine("GET /zipcodes/{zipCode}")
    Optional<ZipCodeView> findByZipCode(@Param(expander = ZipCodeExpander.class) ("zipCode") String zipCode);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting.Unfortunately I found this too much Feign-dependent; what I have in mind - as the OP had probably too given he's using `@FeignClient`, which is a Spring Cloud/OpenFeign annotation - is to be able to use the Java Bean Validation (JSR 380) annotations which are supported de facto in Spring MVC, particularly because the `@GetMapping` is a Spring Web annotation that can be reused in this context (Spring Cloud/OpenFeign) to define the HTTP call/method signature.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811421/how-to-validate-request-parameters-on-feign-client#comment103918234_57958695), a solution using the Bean Validation API would be nice. And indeed, I found in a Spring Boot project that merely placing `@org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated` on the interface is sufficient for enabling Bean Validation.

So for example:

```java
@FeignClient
@Validated
public interface ZipCodeClient {
    @GetMapping("/zipcodes/{zipCode}")
    Optional<ZipCodeView> findByZipCode(@PathVariable("zipCode") @NotEmpty String zipCode);
}
```

triggering a `ConstraintViolationException` in the case of violations.

Any standard Bean Validation feature should work here.

*UDPATE* Note that there seems to be a [potential issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26149) with this solution that might require setting a Hibernate Validator configuration property like this: `hibernate.validator.allow_parallel_method_parameter_constraint=true`